# How do I find out who sent an email on behalf of another user?

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365

An email was sent on behalf of another user that should not have been sent. Multiple people have this permission. How do I find out who sent the email? Assume it's been deleted from sent items. Using Office365 hosted exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have audit log enabled (it isn't by default) in the security and compliance centre it tells you this information.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c

Comment: You must also enable mailbox auditing, and set the actions to be audited.  SendAs and SendonBehalf are auditabled actions.  This is set on a per mailbox basis, and must explicitly be enabled, and it is not retroactive.  You shoudl be able to get the support article by searching for exchange online mailbox auditing ( https://www.bing.com/search?q=exchange+online+mailbox+auditing&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=28e9d736df02494ba167e79ee15a44e6&refig=d43938ae570544f4c8c343cdd496d31e&cc=US&setlang=en-US )

Answer (score 0):

You will want to run a [message trace from the Office 365 administration center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results#go-to-message-trace-from-the-office-365-admin-center). Note that there are different instructions for emails that are either under or over 7 days old.

Comment: Message trace doesn't give me the required information. Message trace tells me the mailbox that was used 'on behalf of', not the person who sent the message. E.g. User A sends a message on behalf of User B. Message trace shows email went out from User B and nothing about User A.